# WebRTC OfferToReceiveAudio error in Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, webrtc

I'm developing a simple example to test WebRTC, and I've found the following strange behaviour.

When using Chrome, the media constraints are specified as:

```
mediaConstraints = {'mandatory': {'OfferToReceiveAudio':true, 'OfferToReceiveVideo':true}};
```

which works fine.

However, when using Firefox (*35.0.1 on the mac*), according to the spec it should be:

```
mediaConstraints = {'offerToReceiveAudio':true,'offerToReceiveVideo':true};
```

But doesn't work (Ice failed!)

Using "**O**fferToReceiveAudio"

```
mediaConstraints = {'OfferToReceiveAudio':true,'offerToReceiveVideo':true};
```

works fine.

Is this documented behaviour?

Answer (score 5):

The right format (by now) is:

```
offerOptions = {'offerToReceiveAudio':true,'offerToReceiveVideo':true};
```

as this is the new [spec format](http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#configuration-data-extensions) and is supported by both [Chrome](https://code.google.com/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=3282) and [Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1033833).

Take special care to note the lower-case 'o's, as this did change and threw more than a few people. Hopefully you got it working by now.

Also note that these are no longer "constraints", just "options". Simpler.

Answer (score 0):

In the specs here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/WebRTC/WebRTC_basics

I see that the constraints should be in the following format:

```
var constraints = {
    mandatory: {
        OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
        OfferToReceiveVideo: true
    }
};
```

Chrome only supports that format.

you can refer to this discussion for same issue:

[WebRTC - getting 'malformed constraints object' from Chrome but not Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830810/webrtc-getting-malformed-constraints-object-from-chrome-but-not-firefox)

Comment: Yes, that's the old way. The second one is the new way of the last spec, that Firefox implements, but not Chrome

Comment: It is bizarre that you are getting this failing error. When I test I only see that OfferToReceiveAudio or OfferToReceiveVideo is deprecated and that I should be using offerToReceiveAudio or offerToReceiveVideo. The call does not fail in either case...

Comment: Yes, the call does not fail, but later I got the message "Ice failed" (not associated to any concrete call)

Comment: @MaximeMarchand - the information in the documentation link was outdated unfortunately and has recently been updated, at least in regard to RTCOfferOptions.