# WebRTC createOffer error <unavailable>

Tags: html, webrtc, sdp, simplewebrtc, peer-connection

Using Firefox 53.0.2 (32bit) on Windows 10 64 bit.

I am getting error  when trying to createOffer on a RTCPeerConnection in which I have not added any local media stream and set

var sdpOptions = { 'mandatory': { 'OfferToReceiveAudio': true, 'OfferToReceiveVideo': true } }

I can´t get more information about it, any ideas on what might be happening or how to get more information?

Best regards,

Comment: Without adding local stream full `localDescription` will not generate. Do you have a sample code to look at?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC OfferToReceiveAudio error in Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323941/webrtc-offertoreceiveaudio-error-in-firefox)

Comment: Use `var sdpOptions = {offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: true};` and curse old WebRTC books.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, sorry but I have never used HTML, i am developing native c++ webrtc app and just testing html5 client, is my first code in HTML5 and I can´t find the proper way to specify the options and which are available, where can I find this?