# WebRTC - getting 'malformed constraints object'

Tags: webrtc

I am using Chrome ans working on a webRTC application. I am getting an error 'malformed constraints object' in the createAnswer() for a session Description offer

```
pc.createAnswer(gotDescription, errorHandler, constraints);
```

I have tried all the options such as

```
constraints = {'mandatory': {
                'offerToReceiveAudio': true,
                'offerToReceiveVideo': true}};
constraints = {'offerToReceiveAudio': true,
           'offerToReceiveVideo': true};
```

and with both capital and small 'o' but still the same error.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WebRTC - getting 'malformed constraints object' from Chrome but not Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27830810/webrtc-getting-malformed-constraints-object-from-chrome-but-not-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems in the latest Specs, the audio/video offers are not required any more in RTCOfferOptions, so you may omit that unless you want to specify the iceRestart option which default is false.

http://w3c.github.io/webrtc-pc/#idl-def-RTCOfferOptions

```
pc.createAnswer(gotDescription, errorHandler);
```

Comment: Bingo! I spent 2 hours in the trying the various options suggested in other posts. This worked.

Comment: Mysteriously there is no clue of offerToReceiveAudio/Video at all anymore. Do they remove it entirely?

Comment: I probably found the reason for this error: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51883609/1520422